# Covering the blood of the Metzora’s bird

Tags: halacha, blood, tzaraas-negaim, birds, kisui-hadam

Does the bird slaughtered for the Metzora’s purification  require covering its blood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rambam [Hilchos Shechita 14:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Ritual_Slaughter.14.2?lang=he)

> וְנוֹהֵג בְּחֻלִּין וְלֹא בְּמֻקְדָּשִׁין. בֵּין קָדְשֵׁי הַמִּזְבֵּחַ בֵּין קָדְשֵׁי בֶּדֶק הַבַּיִת. וְאִם עָבַר וּשְׁחָטָן אֵינוֹ חַיָּב לְכַסּוֹת אֶת דָּמָן

Comment: Is the metzora's bird hekdesh?

Comment: See Kiddushin 57A. It’s assur in hannah like hekdesh and is therefore patur from kissui like hekdesh. See Rambam 14:10 that says any slaughter that doesn’t allow for eating, doesn’t need kissui